# GAE: KindError when getting entities via ListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Contest entity which uses a ListProperty to store keys of Candidate entities.  Here are some details:

```
class Contest(db.Model):
    candidates = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def create_candidate_objects(self):
        put_list = []
        for n, name in enumerate(self.tmp_candidates):
            put_list.append(Candidate(parent = self, name = name))
        keys = db.put(put_list)
        self.candidates = keys
        self.put()

class Candidate(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

When I do this query:

```
c = models.Candidate.all().ancestor(contest).fetch(2)
```

Everything works fine.

But when I do a query using the ListProperty like this:

```
c = db.get(contest.candidates)
```

I get the error

```
KindError: No implementation for kind 'Candidate'
```

Can you help me understand why the last query does not work?  I have imported the Candidate class into the module that is doing the query.

UPDATE: Note that his is on the dev server in case that might make a difference.

UPDATE2:

As suggested by Nick, this works:

```
c2 = models.Candidate.get(contest.candidates)
```

but this does not work (raises KindError):

```
from models import Candidate
c = db.get(contest.candidates)
```

UPDATE3:

The offending line occurs in test code so I can't try this particular failure on the production server.  I have used the exact same line elsewhere and it does work on both the dev and production servers.

Nick asked about imports, and I am doing this in my test code:

```
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/simplejson")
import simplejson as json
```

but everything else is just typical.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're defining `Candidate` in another module you haven't imported. Where is `Candidate` defined? Have you imported the module it's in when you call `db.get`? Calling `Candidate.get(key_list)` should work, since it forces you to have a valid `Candidate` when you call it.

Comment: Nick, the line you suggest does work, but using db.get after importing the Candidate model does not.  Please see the update to my question.

Comment: @Jeff That's pretty surreal. Can you log the contents of `google.appengine.ext.db._kind_map`? Does this happen in both production and on the dev server? Are you messing with imports (reloads, import path) in any unusual manner?

Comment: I will but won't be able to get to it until this weekend.  I've only tried this on the dev server.

Comment: Nick, see UPDATE3 above.  The error occurs in test code (using testbed and webtest) and I have had other unexplainable things occur in test code.  I plan to move on using the workaround you previously gave, but let me know if you would like me to provide more info.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
c = db.get([str(i) for i in contest.candidates])
```

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work.  In fact, although this works, c = models.Candidate.all().ancestor(contest).fetch(2), I can't use the keys of the just retrieved entities to try to get them again, ie, this doesn't work: db.get(c[0].key()).  I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug in the dev server.

Comment: Why on earth would you think this would help?