# nose-gae raises errors about mkstemp and threading

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, nose

Google App Engine seamlessly supports Python's `logging` module. However, it raises errors when I test my code using `nosetests --with-gae`.

To illustrate, if I don't have an `import logging` statement in any of my application scripts, I get the following:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.068s

OK
```

But if I use `import logging`, I get:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.067s

OK
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x101a86750>> ignored
Exception ImportError: 'No module named threading' in <bound method local.__del__ of <_threading_local.local object at 0x103bb4520>> ignored
```

Is there some way I can clean that up?

## Update

I hacked a script to set an environment variable before testing:

```
export TESTING=1
nosetest --with-gae
```

Then in my application code,

```
import os
if not bool(os.environ.get('TESTING')):
    import logging
```

But, it turns out, `import os` also causes `nosetest` to raise the same errors.

Comment: I sometimes get weird errors using nose-gae that are unexplainable (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108130/gae-kinderror-when-getting-entities-via-listproperty) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966685/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-its-not-the-same-object-as-in-gae)).  I have been able to get around them by changing my code but it feels very hackish and unstable.

Comment: @Jeff: It IS strange. For example, I have a code snapshot that spits out those errors. In my frustration, I hack the code, sometimes moving `import`s around. Sometimes the errors come up, sometimes not. And when I give up and manually (not using commit reverts) bring back my original code snapshot, the errors are gone :/

Comment: @Jeff: My latest solution for now is to rewrite the tests incrementally. So far no errors yet.

Comment: Glad you are finding a workaround.  To be fair, it may not be the fault of nose-gae as it could be the dev server or some other package (such as webtest, which I use as well).

Comment: @Jeff, I just posted a hack for it. See if it works for you. I'm not using webtest, just nose and nose-gae.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a temporary hack. I think this is due to the way `nose-gae` prepares the Google App Engine environment. I dug deep into the code and plugged `try` `except` `pass` snippets here and there.

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x101a86750>> ignored
Exception ImportError: 'No module named threading' in <bound method local.__del__ of <_threading_local.local object at 0x103bb4520>> ignored
```

It turns out that the only thing that mattered was the second Exception. I chased it down to `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist/_threading_local.py`. In the function `__del__` of the class `local`, around line 237, there is an `import threading` line. This doesn't throw up any error when running the development server.

But when running `nosetests --with-gae`, it seems that the SDK  cannot access the Python standard libraries for dynamic loading. In experiments leading to this situation, I could not `import inspect` so that I could see who's calling what. I resorted to the manual investigation.

## The Hack

In `/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py`, look for the variable `EXTRA_PATHS`. Add to the path to the Python standard library, like so:

```
EXTRA_PATHS = [
  DIR_PATH,
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django_0_96'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'ipaddr'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'jinja2'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'protorpc'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'markupsafe'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webob'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'webapp2'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'yaml', 'lib'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'simplejson'),
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'google.appengine._internal.graphy'),
  '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
]
```

And the strange errors go away. For now :)

Comment: This isn't fixing my latest GAE-nose testing problem but glad it works for you.